# What happens when you git push but someone else has already committed something you don't have on your local repo?

Tags: git, version-control

Sorry, I'm quite a newbie at Git, and it is hard to find answers for such hard-to-phrase questions (at least for me) on Google.

Say my name is Joe, and I'm working on a software program with my colleague Bob.

We have the upstream `Repo A` and we have clones of `Repo A` on our local machines, where we *code, commit, and push periodically* to the **same branch**, say *master*. I know this is not technically the best way to do it, but for example's sake.

Now, what happens if we are both working on one file.
Bob's *local* file that *he did not yet push* has the contents

```
// awesome program
[some edits by Bob]
```

My local file *that I did not yet push* has the contents

```
// awesome program
[some edits I made]
```

## Bob pushes, a second later I push. What happens now?

Is the file on remote going to be

```
// awesome program
[some edits I made]
```

or

```
// awesome program
[some edits Bob made]
```

or perhaps, if there is a way to do it, I would like it to be

```
// awesome program
[some edits Bob made]
[some edits I made]
```

Sorry for the noobishness :(

Comment: Why not just try? By default, Git will refuse to do not fast forward `push`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Git will refuse your push.  It will tell you there are new changes on the server, and make you do a pull before you can push.  So, you'll end up with

```
// awesome program
[some edits Bob made]
[some edits I made]
```

on your local machine.  Then you'll be able to push that out to the remote.

Comment: @JosephA., `git pull` is explicitly defined as `git fetch` followed by `git merge`. I very much recommend reading [this post](http://longair.net/blog/2009/04/16/git-fetch-and-merge/) for background. And one more thing: *please* read an introductory book on Git before seriously dabbling with it. Your question demonstrates lack of the most basic version control skills, and VC is a complicated task which requires thorough understanding of what you do.

Comment: @JosephA., pulling might also result in "antisocial" behaviour because it breaks "each feature is developed on a separate branch and then merged back into mainline" workflow which is usually *the* standard for serious projects. You can read [this explanation from the Git maintainer](https://git-blame.blogspot.ru/2012/03/fun-with-first-parent.html) for more background. Trigger-happy usage of `git pull` is what breaks the feature/bugfix branch workflow.

Answer (score 5):

First: you can't push in a normal manner with a regular `git push` because when you were on local master your remote master has changed. so *git* propose you to do a force push with -f option. i.e. `git push -f` But Its not recommended to do force push on a shared branch unless you have a fair reason like `interactive rebasing`!

Second: By this message of git you are informed that something is happend to your remote repository so you do a `git status` and yes it tells that `"Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged, and have 1 and 1 different commit(s) each, respectively."`. you should update your local repo; so you are doing a `git pull` or in this situation a better command, `git pull --rebase` and Surprisingly! Git also refuse your pull and tells that you have conflicts in *example* file. that's because both of you and Bob has editing the **same file and the same lines**!

Finally: See this [link](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging#Basic-Merge-Conflicts) and resolve the conflict. you can keep your changes or Bob's or Both. then commit out the changes and `git push` to also update your remote repo. and that's it !!!

Comment: You would need `git push -f` in the case of `interactive rebasing` because after you rebase, the commit SHA will also change. So even if the tip commit of your local has the **same name** as the tip commit of the remote branch, their SHA will be different, right?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure that this is what you are looking to do, but when you commit, there should be a new revision created. Each new revision will replace the previous version. See if this info helps:
[Git Squash Commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5201642/295797)